# android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout not rendering in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-widget, android-support-library

I'm using android studio 1.2.1.1, Although I've added the V4 support library and the app is working perfectly on my phone, the preview window of Android studio is not able to render the drawer layout widget.

[image]
[image]

Comment: In my case that works fine. Did you build the project once? Sometimes you need to compile some ui elements into some caches, else it cannot been displayed.

Comment: try changing  api version 19 to 22 in your xml

Comment: @rekire : I cleaned and built the project multiple times. Still no luck

Comment: @Nilesh:  I did that too. Still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It didn't render because I used `CollapsingToolbarLayout` instead of `android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

Can you post your XML layout file? It could easily be because you use some elements that are in support libraries but not calling them with the `android.support.*` prefix.

Also, your theme in styles.xml must be `Base.Theme.AppCompat` instead of `Theme.Material`. I don't know why but when I set it so all rendering errors disappear.

Comment: It was a bug in the earlier sdk tool, It's now fixed in the latest one.